# MIOpen(HIP): Warning [SQLiteBase] Missing system database file: gfx906_60.kdb Performance may degrade

Tags: docker, pytorch, amd-rocm

I am trying to use ROCm inside of docker, I have followed the [instructions to install MIOpen](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/MIOpen#installing-miopen-kernels-package) on the host system but am still getting this error.